# Delete the column filters in Shiny DT Datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to hide the column filters in `Shiny DT` datatable but I cannot:
[image]

here is my approach:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style("#mydatatable thead > tr:nth-child(2) {display:none;}"),
  mainPanel(
    dataTableOutput("mydatatable")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$mydatatable <- DT::renderDataTable(
    datatable(iris, filter = 'top', options = list(
      pageLength = 5, autoWidth = TRUE)
    )
  )

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Use `datatable(iris, filter = "none", ...)` instead

Comment: that worked thanks

Comment: @GabrielSilva make it an answer, it will help crawlers index it and will help people find a good answer.

Comment: @FaustoCarvalhoMarquesSilva Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide/delete filters by especifying the `filter = "none"` argument of the `DT::datatable` function or as an additional argument of the `DT::renderDataTable` function.

Options for `filter` are any of `c("top", "bottom", "none")`

```r
output$mydatatable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(iris, filter = "none")
  })
```

`renderDataTable` converts a data object (e.g. a dataframe) to a datatable. Additional datatable arguments (`...`) are passed after the `expr` argument. For a list of the possible arguments and options, check the documentation `?DT::datatable`.

```r
output$mydatatable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    iris
  },
  filter = "none"
)
```